# Accept all image mime types except tiff

Tags: filepicker.io

How can I accept all image types except specific ones?  It seems like a pain to list them all out.  Is there any way to name exclusions.  Like everything but tiff?

```
filepicker.pickAndStore
  mimetypes: "image/*"
  container: "modal"
  service: "COMPUTER"
  maxSize: (20 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Comment: I read the documentation, and there is no way to exclude the specific mime type...you use {mimetypes: ['image/jpg', 'image/png','image/gif',.... ]}

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to programmatically exclude mimetypes or extensions. We'll look at adding it, but in most cases we've seen that developers don't actually want the universal exclusion, for example "all images except tiffs" includes things like .tga files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) which you probably don't want either.